# Can a valid ESTA received for business travel be used also for tourism?

Tags: usa, esta

I have acquired an ESTA for business travel which I've done in summer 2022. It is valid till 2024.

This summer (2023) I'd like to visit USA again but this time for pleasure, to visit my brother and family.

Can I use the still valid ESTA or do I need to apply for a new one?

Thanks and best regards,

Tayfun

Comment: I don't understand. ESTA is a tourism visa. For Business you need a regular Visum.

Comment: @Lovntola ESTA is an authorization granted to visa-waiver nationals for both B1 (business) and B2 (tourism) entries.

Comment: @Lovntola the first FAQ on the page linked in my answer is "What is the Visa Waiver Program?
The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) is administered by DHS and enables eligible citizens or nationals of designated countries to travel to the United States for tourism **or business** for stays of 90 days or less without first obtaining a visa." (Emphasis added)  In the language of the immigration statute, it's actually"business or pleasure," so even "tourism" is deceptive; many non-touristic "pleasure" purposes are also included.

Comment: Then, to establish the link between the VWP and ESTA, see the first FAQ under "General Information about ESTA," which is "What is the Electronic System for Travel Authorization?
The Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA) is an automated system that assists in determining eligibility to travel to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) and whether such travel poses any law enforcement or security risk. Upon completion of an ESTA application, a traveler is notified of his or her eligibility to travel to the United States under the VWP."

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76735/use-same-us-esta-for-different-purposes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use your existing ESTA.  From https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel:

> How long is a travel authorization via ESTA valid?
>
> ...
>
> A new travel authorization is required if: (1) the traveler is issued a new passport; (2) the traveler changes his or her name; (3) the traveler changes his or her gender; (4) the traveler’s country of citizenship changes; or (5) the circumstances underlying the traveler’s previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response have changed. The associated fee will be charged for each new application submitted.

Since the purpose of your trip is not a question "requiring a “yes” or “no” response," you do not need to reapply for ESTA if you want to travel to the US for a different purpose.

(The purpose must of course be a purpose that is allowed under the visa waiver program, which is the case here.)